# How to Export sqlflite db to some selected folder in device

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I want to export the Sqlfite database in a flutter program using Sqlfite. I want to export that database to some selected folder(using file_picker) in a device. I want the exported file to be an excel file or data base file.